# Basic SQL joining two select statements

Tags: sql

I have two select statements that work just fine separately, but I don't know how to put them together into one resulting table.  I've been trying SELECT INTO or creating temporary tables, but I am just not getting anywhere.  Hoping that if I post the two select statements below, it'll take someone 30 seconds to point me in the right direction.

```
SELECT EMEQP#, EMLYR$, SUM(EQCRRV) AS SUM_REV
FROM WSDATA.EQPMASFL
LEFT JOIN WSDATA.CREQURFL ON EMCMP = EQCMP AND EMEQP# = EQEQP#
WHERE EMEQP# IN ('10925592','10935431','11192212') AND EQPERD >=202101 AND EQPERD <=202112
GROUP BY EMEQP#, EMLYR$

SELECT EMEQP#, EMLYRM AS PARTS, EMLYRL AS LABOR, EMLYRM + EMLYRL AS PARTS_LABOR, SUM(RHAMT$) AS R_M
FROM WSDATA.EQPMASFL 
LEFT JOIN WSDATA.WOHEADFL ON EMCMP = VHCMP AND EMEQP# = VHEQP#
LEFT JOIN WSDATA.RACHDRFL ON RHCMP = VHCMP AND RHCON# = VHWO#
WHERE EMEQP# IN ('10925592','10935431','11192212') AND VHDATC >= '20210101' AND VHDATC <= '20211231' AND VHBCOL = 'L'
GROUP BY EMEQP#, EMLYRM, EMLYRL, EMLYRM + EMLYRL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two major pieces of information is missing.

1. what is the primary key of the table?
2. What kind of database is this?

It's a bit confusing on what the tables look like, but I'm going to assume that EMEQP# is a primary key in the EQPMASFL table.

if that's the case, you can perform a join using a couple of CTEs.  if that's not the case, you have to add a field to each query that can be joined when the queries output.

you can do this:

```
with q1 as (
     SELECT EMEQP#, EMLYR$, SUM(EQCRRV) AS SUM_REV
     FROM WSDATA.EQPMASFL
     LEFT JOIN WSDATA.CREQURFL ON EMCMP = EQCMP AND EMEQP# = EQEQP#
     WHERE EMEQP# IN ('10925592','10935431','11192212') AND EQPERD >=202101 AND 
     EQPERD <=202112
     GROUP BY EMEQP#, EMLYR$
), q2 as (
     SELECT EMEQP#, EMLYRM AS PARTS, EMLYRL AS LABOR, EMLYRM + EMLYRL AS 
     PARTS_LABOR, SUM(RHAMT$) AS R_M
     FROM WSDATA.EQPMASFL 
     LEFT JOIN WSDATA.WOHEADFL ON EMCMP = VHCMP AND EMEQP# = VHEQP#
     LEFT JOIN WSDATA.RACHDRFL ON RHCMP = VHCMP AND RHCON# = VHWO#
     WHERE EMEQP# IN ('10925592','10935431','11192212') AND VHDATC >= 
     '20210101' AND VHDATC <= '20211231' AND VHBCOL = 'L'
     GROUP BY EMEQP#, EMLYRM, EMLYRL, EMLYRM + EMLYRL
) select * from q1
full outer join q2 on q1.EMEQP# = q2.EMEQP#
```

The reason why I"m doing this in this manner is due to the different filtering criteria in each query.  with the cte's (see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)), you can use the output as data sources for follow on queries.

This comes at a cost, if you do a large query that references the cte, the cte requires each time.  so use them sparingly.

Comment: This is great.
You are correct, EMEQP# is the primary key.

Any way to drop the second EMEQP# field that shows up in the results?

Comment: Yeah. Change the * to q1.col1, q1.col2, q2.col1, q2.col2 etc…